# How do i rotate object A to Object B if Object A's rotation is relative to Object C

Tags: math, matrix, vector

COnsider having 3 Objects: A,B,C. Each have their own matrix.

Object A's Rotation is relative to C (A facing vector of [0,0,1] on Object A will always point towards the facing vector of Object C rather than along the z axis of the world.)

Now say Object B is separate to both of these objects and simply exists in the same world space. How would one go about rotating Object A so that it's facing vector points towards Object B. I've been trying to figure the maths for this out and I'm really struggling

(I haven't put any code because I'm using my own class libraries for this so I don't think it would be particularly helpful, its just standard matrices and vectors)

Comment: I think you're being a little careless about your language. Each of these objects has a location (which is a vector), a direction (which is a vector) and a reference frame. Initially A points to C (that is, A's direction vector **a** is parallel to the difference in their locations, **C** - **A** ). And you want to rotate A so that it points to B instead. Is that correct so far?

Comment: Kind of. If A has a facing vector of [0,0,1] it will always point to the direction of C regardless of C's facing vector as it is relative to C. My language may be misleading sorry! I basically have a turret that is relative to a body. I want the turret to aim at an object in the scene but this is difficult as it's rotation is relative to it's body's axis not the worlds